# Why is filepond sending a GET request at my server index when I remove a preloaded file?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, filepond

Hi I'm using React filepond to upload files to our server and everything works fine for the most part.

The problem is when I have preloaded files, if I try to remove one of them Filepond sends a GET request to http://myserver.domain/12345.jpg

I don't know why this request is sent and this is not even an available endpoint on my server so it always returns an error with status 404.

My filepond instance is configured like this :

```
export default function FileField({
    name,
    control,
    rules,
    defaultValue = null,
    isMultiple,
    fileTypes,
    component_id,
}) {
    const [files, setFiles] = useState(defaultValue || []);

    // Controller from React-Hook-Form
    //(It's used to save the list of files for later use)
    const { field } = useController({ name, control, rules, defaultValue });

    // Filepond ref
    const pond = useRef(null);

    const handleChange = () => {
        let files = pond.current.getFiles();

        // Set the value of the control field
        field.onChange(
            files.map((f) => {
                return { source: f.serverId, options: { type: 'local' } };
            })
        );
        field.onBlur();
    };

    return (
        <div className='px-4 py-4 rounded bg-window-accent'>
            <FilePond
                ref={(ref) => (pond.current = ref)}
                files={files}
                onupdatefiles={setFiles}
                onprocessfile={handleChange}
                onremovefile={handleChange}
                required={rules.required.value}
                allowMultiple={isMultiple}
                server={`/api/files/${component_id}`}
                name={'file'}
                acceptedFileTypes={fileTypes}
                disabled={rules.disabled}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

When loading the file the correct endpoint is used GET /api/files/12345?load=12345.jpg

It's just when I click on the (X) The file is removed correctly from the input field but there's that additional GET Request that makes no sense...

This error does not happen when a file is reverted after being just uploaded, only happens when the file is preloaded in the files with option type="local".

[The error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1s6ve.png)

What can I do to stop filepond from sending this extra request ?